# log4net cannot find custom XmlLayoutBase

Tags: c#, web-services, log4net

I am attempting to use an overridden XmlLayoutBase with log4net to print a custom log. It was working yesterday but I did some restructuring and now it is blowing up. Here is what I have done so far.

AssemblyInfo.cs

`[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4net.config", Watch = true)]`

CustomXmlLayout.cs

```
namespace MyCompany.MyProduct.MyService.Utilities

public class CustomXmlLayout : XmlLayoutBase  
{  
    protected override void FormatXml(XmlWriter writer, LoggingEvent loggingEvent)  
    {  
        //Write stuff
    }  
}
```

log4net.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<log4net>
  <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="logfile" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Date" />
    <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd'.xml'" />
    <staticLogFileName value="false" />
    <maxSizeRollbackups value="15" />
    <layout type="MyCompany.MyProduct.MyService.Utilities.CustomXmlLayout" />   
  </appender>
  <root>
    <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
  </root>
</log4net>
```

Log.cs

```
public static class Log
{
    private static ILog log = 
        log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Log));

    static Log()
    {
        XmlConfigurator.Configure();
    }

    private static bool IsEnabled()
    {
        //Verify stuff
    }

    public static void Write(LogEntry entry)
    {            
        if (IsEnabled())
            log.Debug(entry);
    }
}
```

For whatever reason the call to `log.Debug` never reaches the `FormatXml` in my custom class. Anyone have any ideas?

*edit* It works fine when I put the log4net configuration back in web.config, so I guess its some probably with the assemblyinfo... but I don't see what

Comment: Have you checked your output window for any errors that might be occurring behind the scenes?

Comment: Its giving me: `log4net:ERROR XmlConfigurator: Failed to find configuration section 'log4net' in the application's .config file.` but in AssemblyInfo I am directing it to look in log4net.config instead of web.config? Do I still need the config tag in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up leaving the config section in the web.config

Answer (score 0):

In examples where I've seen this working, the log4net configuration was stored in a file called `log4net.config` (as you have), *without* the xml declaration e.g. `<?xml version="1.0"?>` - give that a try

Answer (score 0):

You should add configsections to your log4net.config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>

    </configSections>

    <log4net>
       <!-- LOG4NET configuration-->
    </log4net>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are configuring log4net twice. Remove the static constructor of the Log class.

Comment: Does configuring twice makes any problem?

Comment: not exactly but calling the Configure method makes log4net look in web.config instead of log4net.config

Answer (score 0):

You are not specifying the assembly for your type:

`<layout type="MyCompany.MyProduct.MyService.Utilities.CustomXmlLayout" />`

Should be:

`<layout type="MyCompany.MyProduct.MyService.Utilities.CustomXmlLayout, assemblyname" />`

Where **assemblyname** is your output dll.